# Extra space between perl /sed replacement

Tags: sed, perl

Below command is used to replace the password in a script but the perl command is adding a white space when it does the subsstitution

```
password=arche20
perl -i -p -e "s/^(password[]*=[ ]*).*$/\1 $passwd/" config.properties

cat config.properties
userid=ARCHE
password= arche20
```

It does the work but it seems to be adding a space after password when it replaces. 
Could this be done without the space?
Got a `sed` way:

```
sed -i "s/password.*/password=$passwd/g"
```

Comment: I got a sed way to do it .. but want to correct the perl way as well                       sed -i "s/password.*/password=$passwd/g"

Comment: You can use that exact same command in perl. Why are you adding the `[ ]`? All you need is `perl -i -pe "s/^(password *= *).*/\1$passwd/"`. Are the empty character classes supposed to be doing something?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You have a space after `\1` in your replacement, just remove that and you should be good

```
perl -i -p -e "s/^(password[]*=[ ]*).*$/\1$passwd/" config.properties
                                          ^
                                          Removed space here
```